# Criar uma directive que force o bind de um formulá

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directives

Seguindo uma publicação de [Fernando Mantoan](http://blog.fernandomantoan.com/angularjs-forcando-bind-de-todos-os-campos-no-submit/), a coisa parace se bem simple, cria-se a directive:

```
myApp.directive('forceBind',  function() {
  return {
    require: '^form',
    priority: -1,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, form) {
      element.bind('submit', function() {
        if (form.$valid) {
          angular.forEach(form, function(value, key) {  
            if (value.hasOwnProperty('$modelValue')) {
              if (!value.$viewValue) {
                value.$setViewValue("");
              }
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

E o problema seria solucionado, ele até mostra o [código funcionando](http://jsfiddle.net/pgfLaomd/3/).

Só que quando fui fazer na minha aplicação, olha só o que apareceu:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de uns dois dias pesquisando, descobri que esse erro seria por conta da versão do angular,  ele usa a versão [1.2.1](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js). Daí começa meus problemas, pois eu uso a versão 1.6.3 no angular, e já tentei de tudo para mudar sintax, mas acredito que eu não tenho o conhecimento necessário. :(

Aqui vai a parte do código onde eu faço a utilização da directive no form:

```
<form  force-bind ng-model="formUsuario" name="formUsuario"  ng-submit="salvarUsuario()" autocomplete='off'>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
        <h1>Dados Pessoais</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="control-group">
            <input  class="form-control"  type="text" placeholder="Matrícula" floating-label ng-model="usuario.matricula" ng-disabled="{desabilita}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="control-group">
            <input  class="form-control"  type="text" placeholder="Nome" floating-label ng-model="usuario.nome" required />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="control-group">
            <input  class="form-control"  type="text" placeholder="E-mail" floating-label ng-model="usuario.email"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="floating-label ng-valid ng-not-empty">
                <label class="active" for="perfil_id">Perfil</label>
                <select id="perfil_id" class="form-control" ng-model="usuario.perfil_id" ng-options="v.id as v.descricao for (k, v) in perfis" ng-disabled="{desabilita}">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="floating-label ng-valid ng-not-empty">
                <label class="active" for="ativo">Ativo</label>
                <select id="ativo" class="form-control" ng-model="usuario.ativo" ng-disabled="{desabilita}">
                    <option value="1">Ativo</option>
                    <option value="2">Desativado</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="control-group">
            <input  class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Senha Atual" floating-label ng-model="usuario.senhaAtual" ng-trim="false" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="control-group">
            <input  class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Nova Senha" floating-label ng-model="usuario.novaSenha" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="control-group">
            <input  class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Senha Confirmada" floating-label ng-model="usuario.senhaConfirmada" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="btnSalvar" ng-disabled="formLogin.$invalid || formUsuario.$pristine || btnCarregando.ativo">
            <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate" ng-class="{'hidden':!btnCarregando.ativo}"></div>
            {{btnCarregando.ativo ? btnCarregando.mensagem : 'Salvar lterações'}}
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Acredito que de código seja suficiente, a directive e o html que faz a chamada do force-bind, caso seja necessário algo a mais só comentar que eu adiciono.

A grande questão é como fazer um force-bind para angular js na versão 1.6.3 evitando o erro:

```
ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
at force-bind.js:13
at Object.forEach (angular.js:424)
at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (force-bind.js:12)
at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.js:5206)
at HTMLFormElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.2.1.js:5014)
   (anonymous) @ force-bind.js:13
   forEach @ angular.js:424
   (anonymous) @ force-bind.js:12
   dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.js:5206
   elemData.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.js:5014
```

E conseguir fazer um input seja identificado ao se enviado para o backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me pergunto, como buscar uma propriedade que não está declarada no código?
usei essa adaptação do código:

```
tcc.directive('forceBind',  function() {
return {
    require: '^form',
    priority: -1,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, form) {
        element.bind('submit', function() {
            if (form.$valid) {
                angular.forEach(form, function(value, key) {
                    if(typeof value == 'object'){
                        if (value.hasOwnProperty('$modelValue')) {
                            if (!value.$viewValue) {
                                value.$setViewValue("");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
};
});
```

Com a `directive` acima o erro não era mais apresentado, mas também não era forçado o bing dos campus no momento de enviar o código, só depois de muito tempo percebi que, eu não estava usando o atribulo `name` nos `inputs`, fazendo com que o erro fosse apresentado.

Só fiz colocar o atributo  `name` e tudo começou a funcionar:

```
<div class="control-group">
     <input  class="form-control" name="teste3"type="password" placeholder="Senha Confirmada" floating-label ng-model="usuario.senhaConfirmada" />
</div>
```

Referencias:

[Exemplo 1, nesse exemplo todos os campos tem o atributo name](https://plnkr.co/edit/xclAhOP2ryzyLGQoxHq3?p=preview)

[Exemplo 2, nesse exemplo NEM todos os campos tem o atributo name, mas o que tem funciona](https://plnkr.co/edit/XQWcDjZg989oPTz0nZtf?p=preview)